# how to make toggled title stay after mouse out function is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/Fzs7u/

I have thumbnails and titles that toggle when a `mouseover` function occurs. How can I make the title remain from the last hovered thumbnail? Should I use something other than `toggle`? Perhaps target the css `display` rule?

```
$(".thumbnail-wrapper").on("mouseover mouseout", "img", function () {
  $("#" + $(this).data("title")).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Fzs7u/3/

```
$(".thumbnail-wrapper").on("mouseover", "img", function () {
  $('.title:visible').hide();
  $("#" + $(this).data("title")).show();
});
```

---

I changed your .toggle() to .show(), and hid .title on mouseover, to make sure that only one title is displayed at a time. Also removed your mouseout handler.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to have one of the titles displayed first as well before the user starts hovering?

Comment: reselecting the visible/currently shown element makes the code concise/short but doing so may have inefficient performance, however we can confine the context just to the container of the visible element, then there should not be any notable issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to hide the caption, I'd do things a little differently:

http://jsfiddle.net/zZ6UJ/

```
<div class="editable title" id="title">
</div>

<div class="thumbnail-wrapper repeatable">
    <img src="http://intelligen.info/images/LFW Live Show Drawings/Vivienne Westwood/2013/img012_2.jpg" alt="1" data-title="Vivienne Westwood"/>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-wrapper repeatable">
    <img src="http://intelligen.info/images/LFW Live Show Drawings/Vivienne Westwood/2013/img013_3.jpg" alt="2" data-title="Paul Smith"/>
</div>
```

---

```
$(".thumbnail-wrapper").on("mouseover", "img", function () {
    $("#title").text($(this).data('title'));
});
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that you can't display anything other than a single, unformatted line of text. For anything more complex, I would go with a modification of the original fiddle, like the example I have posted.

Comment: @Steve html works too: http://jsfiddle.net/V72Wh/, granted you probably don't want to have super complex html in an attribute like that.

Comment: Both answers work but I like this solution.  While it does deviate slightly from the initial post, the code winds up being cleaner. Having each one of those DIV's be rendered separately smells funny.  Using the one DIV as a template (instead of multiple) and loading the data into it allows for the style to be applied based on the selection.